# Visual Studio Lightswitch Duplicate Button

Tags: button, duplicates, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have added a button to the end of each row in the editable grid, what I want this button to do is duplicate the row into the next. Can anyone help me? Some data entered will be similar so want a duplicate button to stop entering everything twice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I do this in order to create revisions of quotes. In your button code, make a local copy of the selected revision. Then add a new quote to the collection which then becomes the selected revision. Finally copy the necessary data from the old revision to the new revision.

**VB.NET:**

```vb
'Create a quote object to hold the quote to be revised
Dim CurrentRev As Quote
CurrentRev = Me.qQuoteByFirm.SelectedItem

'Add a new quote entity to the database
Me.qQuoteByFirm.AddNew()

'Copy the necessary relevant values to the new quote
Me.qQuoteByFirm.SelectedItem.QuoteNumber = CurrentRev.QuoteNumber
Me.qQuoteByFirm.SelectedItem.Customer = CurrentRev.Customer
Me.qQuoteByFirm.SelectedItem.Status = CurrentRev.Status
Me.qQuoteByFirm.SelectedItem.RevNumber = CurrentRev.RevNumber + 1

'Remove IsCurrent status from previous rev of quote
CurrentRev.IsCurrent = False

'Set the new quote as current
Me.qQuoteByFirm.SelectedItem.IsCurrent = True

'Save new revision to the databse
Me.Save()

'Open a modal window for editing of the newly added quote
Me.editRevision_Execute()
```

**C#:**

```cs
// Create a quote object to hold the quote to be revised
Quote CurrentRev;
CurrentRev = this.qQuoteByFirm.SelectedItem;

// Add a new quote entity to the database
this.qQuoteByFirm.AddNew();

// Copy the necessary relevant values to the new quote
this.qQuoteByFirm.SelectedItem.QuoteNumber = CurrentRev.QuoteNumber;
this.qQuoteByFirm.SelectedItem.Customer = CurrentRev.Customer;
this.qQuoteByFirm.SelectedItem.Status = CurrentRev.Status;
this.qQuoteByFirm.SelectedItem.RevNumber = (CurrentRev.RevNumber + 1);

// Remove IsCurrent status from previous rev of quote
CurrentRev.IsCurrent = false;

// Set the new quote as current
this.qQuoteByFirm.SelectedItem.IsCurrent = true;

// Save new revision to the database
this.Save();

// Open a modal window for editing of the newly added quote
this.editRevision_Execute();
```

Comment: @lesleyrae_xo Ar you calling the button's `_Execute` method at the end? If you want, you can edit your question and include you code so I can have a look.